# Download data from firebase

Tags: firebase, swift

[image: Dowbn]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de ajuda para poder efetuar o download das informações dentro do "Itens". Pois como seria uma lista criada pelo usuario, eu não colocaria um limite de itens nela, e ao mesmo tempo eu não saberia dizer quantos dados existe.

Gostaria de saber qual a melhor maneira de efetuar isso. Se eu retirar a parte como comentario "Let Itens = value["Itens"] as: String" o código não executa.

Desde já agradeço a ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver.
Vou deixar registrado como resolvi, espero ajudar o proximo que tenha dúvida semelhante.

Retornei o valor de Lista para uma variavel string (Name).

Usei o didselect (tableview) para passar a informação variavel, para uma outra viewController.
Nesta view controller, criei uma função, onde recebe a seguinte informação.

[image: ![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

//ObjectsArray é um array empty criado fora do didViewLoad, para receber os dados do array firebase, e após isso conseguir utilizar na tableView.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
//Lembre-se de usar o reloadData, ligar todos os outlet necessarios e usar o tableview.delegate = self e tableview.datasource = self.